# Join two one-to many tables on different databases to compare the many items

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables on two databases on same server, each with a one to many relationship on the Asset/Equipment.  I need to compare the Asset/Equipment in the two databases.

Here are the tables on one database-

Database 1:

Table1:
**Application - one**
-APP_KEY primary key

Table2:
**Asset - many**
-AS_APP_FKEY *foreign key*
-SampleAsset1
-SampleAsset2
-SampleAsset3

Database 2:

Table3:
**Application - one**
-ApplicationId *primary key*
-App_Key *nullable, this ends up being the APP_KEY on database 1*

Table4:
**Equipment - many**
-EquipID primary key
-ApplicationId *foreign key of application*
-SampleEquip1
-SampleEquip2
-SampleEquip3

Is there a way to make a query to show SampleEquip1 next to sampleAsset1 based on these relationships.

Edit:

This is the query I have tried but it creates duplicate items. For example if there is four items in each child table it creates 8 comparison rows with duplicates and distinct doesn't remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT app.APP_KEY,
       e.SampleEquip1,
       secondDb.APP_KEY,
       secondDb.SampleAsset1
FROM dabatase1.dbo.Application app
JOIN database1.dbo.Equipment e
    ON e.ApplicationId = app.ApplicationId
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT ap.APP_KEY,
           a.SampleAsset1
    FROM database2.dbo.Application ap
    JOIN database2.dbo.Asset a
        ON a.AS_APP_FKEY = ap.APP_KEY
) secondDb
    ON secondDb.APP_KEY = app.APP_KEY
WHERE app.APP_KEY = 123
```

Comment: A regular join using 3-part names should do it (same server) or 4-part (linked servers) assuming permissions are in place

Comment: Sure this should be doable. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/